# How do I transfer SPECIFICALLY an Image file to from client to server using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, function, server, client, paramiko

So I wanna transfer an IMAGE file from client to server using Python Paramiko. For example: jpg, jpeg, png.

This is my code:

(assume the create client code has already been created)

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab # Line 1
sftp_client = client.open_sftp() # Line 2                 
ImageGrab.grab().save("screenshot.png") # Line 3
sftp_client.put("screenshot.png", "/home") # Line 4
```

I don't get an error, but on line 4 it always prints:

```
Failure
```

This works fine with any other type of file besides an image file.

If I missed any information that might help please tell me.

Comment: Whenever I encounter problems like this I make sure that first it's not an issue with the path to the file being relative.  Try to first create an arbitrary text file and then put the absolute path  into the put call and see if it works.  Besides not closing the connection and assuming the initialization of client is correct nothing really jumps at me now. Maybe you can post your complete code so I can try to reproduce your error.

Comment: @ShaanK I am able to perfectly send another file that is not a picture. I also do not think I will be able to post my full code considering it is like 500 lines.

Comment: Depending on what your local OS is you could try executing an scp command using paramiko or maybe try a solution like this: https://python.tutorialink.com/upload-large-file-using-multiple-connections-threads-to-an-sftp-server-with-python-paramiko/

Comment: I cannot believe that your code with `remotepath="/home"` works for non-image files. It cannot. Double check that.